# NSArray element comparison to NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to find a word inside a phrase (NSString).

For this I've exploded the components of the phrase into individual substrings and now I am trying to compare them to the word I am looking for, but it doesn't work.

What would be the correct approach for this and fix for the software below?

```
NSString *myString = @"Mi Programa es genial";
NSArray *explodedDescription = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

if ([explodedDescription objectAtIndex:1] == @"Programa" ) {
    NSLog(@"Found");
}
```

Comment: Note that splitting by a space character is a pretty naive approach. The text may be in a language which uses a different separator, or may have a newline character without any space.

Comment: Or it may be the final word in a clause (thus including a comma, a semicolon, or terminal punctuation such as a full stop), or it may be the first or not the first word, thereby differing in capitalization, or it may not be the root version of the word: it may be a gerund, comparative, superlative, past tense, past participle, or any other derivative of the root.

Comment: The only real solution is to parse the string using an actual parser that's aware of the many forms of punctuation, and look for words using a database that can connect roots with derivatives (e.g., match “searching” when searching for “search”) and a comparator that can account for typos (e.g., “sarching” or “saerching” or “searthing”). Even then, brace yourself for lots and lots of edge cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSStrings are compared with isEqualToString.
You're comparing pointers instead of the values.

See [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it the hard way!  Use NSString's [-rangeOfString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_) method or one of its variants to get the location of a string in another string.

Comment: That won't work for *words*, since it will happily detect one word in another word. Naïve swear-filters are the most common victim; in that context, it's called the Scunthorpe problem (after a town in the UK whose name you can't say under a dumb swear-filter).

Comment: Obviously, you'd do word-boundary analysis for each result and continue the search if the result fails the check.  See NSAttributedString's doubleClickAtIndex: method.